# Is there a positive synonym for "indecisive"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, connotation

Is there a word that describes a person who tries to get as much information as possible when making a decision for fear of committing a mistake that might affect both him and others in a negative fashion?

The only word I could think of was *indecisive,* but it has a connotation that suggests hesitation and irresolution when making decisions, which is not what I'm going for, since I want a sense of absolute commitment when making the decision.

Comment: Analysis paralysis.

Comment: _Methodical_ might do the job. A lot depends on the context, as usual.

Comment: "Overly cautious"

Answer (score 11):

[analytical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analytical):

> skilled in or using analysis especially in thinking or reasoning

[deliberate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deliberate):

> characterized by or resulting from careful and thorough consideration
>
> characterized by awareness of the consequences

[judicious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/judicious):

> having, exercising, or characterized by sound judgment

A few more options: rational, prudent, sensible.

Comment: +1 I particularly like *deliberate*, since it is (at least in American jurisprudence) a celebrated retardant of overhasty action: see "with all deliberate speed" in [Safire's Political Dictionary](http://books.google.com/books/about/Safire_s_Political_Dictionary.html?id=c4UoX6-Sv1AC), p.815353.

Comment: Yes, of the ones I listed, "deliberate" might be the best fit for what the OP describes. I think it's mostly a positive term. Even though it can also be used sarcastically. For example "he is very deliberate" can mean "he's taking way too long to make up his mind" depending on the context, and on how you say it.

Comment: Of course anything can be inverted by using it sarcastically; I ***might*** have meant '+1' sarcastically (but I assure you I did not).

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest *meticulous*.

Meticulous suggests that someone is gathering information to ensure that  all details and options are covered. This can be a result of acting *methodically* or otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use *circumspect*.

> adj. watchful and discreet; cautious; prudent: circumspect behavior.

[[R H K Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/circumspect)]

Answer (score 4):

[Rigorous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rigorous) - "scrupulously accurate, manifesting rigor, done carefully and with a lot of attention to detail" - [Usage:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rigorous)"He is rigorous in his control of expenditure".

[Painstaking](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/painstaking) - "expending, showing, or involving diligent care and effort" Usage: "she was always painstaking about her work."

[Exhaustive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exhaustive)- "comprehensive in scope; thorough: an exhaustive survey." Usage: "He was exhaustive in his search for the necklace".

Answer (score 2):

Consider *[scrupulous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scrupulous)*

> (Of a person or process) diligent, thorough, and extremely attentive to details:
>   the research has been carried out with scrupulous attention to detail [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Comment: +1 I immediately thought of *thorough* and *diligent* and had always thought of *scrupulous* as having to do with *scruples* which I always connect with *ethics* but the dictionary seems to indicate this is *exactly* the word OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest: open-minded, ponderous, judicial, sparing, non-judgmental, reserved (as in reserving judgment)